# Apache HTTPD hostname resolution

Tags: apache

I read a lot of hostname resolution specific Apache-HTTPD documentation, but I'm not able to configure a VirtualHost without an entry in /etc/hosts.

The configuration:

```
...
ServerName "localhost"
HostnameLookups Off
LogFormat "%a %v %l %u %t...   # no %h
...
Listen 127.0.0.100:8080
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.100:8080>
  DocumentRoot "/home/apache/htdocs"
  ServerName mywebserver
  ServerAlias mywebserveralias
</VirtualHost>
...
```

Requests to this apache will be forwarded by a local nginx proxy.

=> This configuration works.

=> BUT: It is very, very slow (incl. timeouts) without the following entries in /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.100 mywebserver
127.0.0.100 mywebserveralias
```

Why needs Apache this DNS entries? I have configured the IP and the ServerName should only be a "string" that will be searched in the request headers.

===> Is it possible to configure apache without this /etc/hosts entries.

Comment: just to be sure, is it normal that you use 127.0.0.100 and not 127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: Yes, I have a lot of 127.0.0.0/8 adresses for different services behind proxies, this shouldn't be a problem.